# Publish and go to page

Tags: publish, wp-link-pages

Can I add a link to "Publish"-button so when it's clicked it publishes new post and direct to another page in same click?

Answer (score 0):

You can using `redirect_post_location` action in the functions.php in your theme.

For example:

```
add_action('redirect_post_location', function () {
    global $post;
    return 'http://google.com/search?q=' . $post->ID;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I just saw the answer and duplicate so it's fine now. Thanks for helping out :).